# Rowwise matrix multiplication of two matrix columns in dplyr

Tags: dplyr, rotation, matrix-multiplication

I have a tibble called `to_rotate`:

```r
# A tibble: 32 x 3
   personID bun_xyz               mat_y            
      <int> <list>                <list>           
 1        1 <dbl[,3] [1,381 x 3]> <dbl[,3] [3 x 3]>
 2        2 <dbl[,3] [3,714 x 3]> <dbl[,3] [3 x 3]>
 3        3 <dbl[,3] [3,157 x 3]> <dbl[,3] [3 x 3]>
 4        4 <dbl[,3] [3,705 x 3]> <dbl[,3] [3 x 3]>
# ... with 28 more rows
```

I would like to do rowwise matrix multiplication of the two list columns, but how do I do it?

I tried this:

```r
to_rotate %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(rotated = map2(bun_xyz, mat_y, ~ .x %*% .y))
```

but I get the error:

```
Error: Mapped vectors must have consistent lengths:
* `.x` has length 4143
* `.y` has length 9
```

If I just take one row and do it "manually", everything is fine:

```r
> rotated_1 = to_rotate$bun_xyz[[1]] %*% to_rotate$mat_y[[1]]
> head(rotated_1)

          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.4411675 0.7639250 0.3506840
[2,] 0.4438372 0.7625611 0.3518184
[3,] 0.4458833 0.7618375 0.3535549
[4,] 0.4452629 0.7607695 0.3538486
[5,] 0.4404777 0.7533813 0.3511128
[6,] 0.4398552 0.7514426 0.3508681
```

(`bun_xyz` are some 3D-coordinates which need to be rotated around the y-axis. `mat_y` is the matrix that can do this)

Comment: Please remove rowwise and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `rowwise()` did the trick:

```
to_rotate %>%
    mutate(rotated = map2(bun_xyz, mat_y, ~ .x %*% .y))
```

Thanks Mossa Nova for pointing this out in a comment.